# IPhone breaking up my string cause of "&" in soap response from Server

Tags: iphone, string, soap

I receive a response from my server and data is parsed correctly all the time except for when a address contain the character "&" It splits my string cause the parser to get no objects

An Example of a string that will fail and not parse

[{"ID":["3bc06ce8-222e-49ee-beac-ba26782f0e7e"],"SiteName":["Home"],"SiteAddress":["123 Home"]},{"ID":["2987e94e-3cf6-4106-81bb-67c255963b6c"],"SiteName":["Work"],"SiteAddress":["123 Work"]},{"ID":["235019b9-3b0c-40e6-9d68-a86e6738a9d6"],"SiteName":["(null)"],"SiteAddress":["home "]},{"ID":["02edf5df-e9c7-4e5e-8667-8ea7a7f06048"],"SiteName":["test"],"SiteAddress":["test"]},{"ID":["280d92a0-e395-4114-9a47-66398c4c04cf"],"SiteName":["asd"],"SiteAddress":["asdasd"]},{"ID":["a0cc0439-4f2f-48fe-b155-dcbc3a07bd41"],"SiteName":["test"],"SiteAddress":["test

//Next Line

&

//Next Line

test"]}]

That is the what one NSLog  spits out. Normally it would just spit out string on one line but the "&" Any ideas on what I can do to fix this string it works like other strings and does not recognize the & and keep it as one string
?

Answer (score 0):

I had similar problem ... it was causingbecause of "\n" not the "&".. and I see in your code.. ..Next Line.. in any of the cases.. I would suggest to replace the "\n" to empty string and try.. if problem still persists then see if it can fix by replacing "&" to **escape character**..

**EDIT**

I had one \n coming from rss feed.. I used

> NSString *scannedString = nil;
>   NSScanner *scanner = [NSScanner scannerWithString:rssDateString];
>   [scanner scanUpToString:@"\n" intoString:&scannedString];

I guess you have two.. give a try ... it should work..

Comment: I don't have \n the // next line is just to show how the console shows the string on 3 different lines. In my soap respone before the xml envelope is removed that "&" is just  &amp;    Also I am just wondering how would replace the & in my string?

Comment: I believe console is showing on 3 different lines because it has \n in it.. and that's what breaking the code..

Comment: oh i see, didnt notice that, I'll try that and see what happens, thanks

Comment: I tried your method but it is not changing anything, I also tried using stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString but it did not work also.